# How to group an array with multiple parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array as followed:

```
let arr = [InventoryItem(capacity: "1T", chainLength: 55, speed: "32FPM", voltage: "110V", frameSize: "Small", controlStation: "None"),
       InventoryItem(capacity: "1T", chainLength: 55, speed: "32FPM", voltage: "110V", frameSize: "Small", controlStation: "None"),
       InventoryItem(capacity: "1T", chainLength: 55, speed: "32FPM", voltage: "110V", frameSize: "Small", controlStation: "None"),
       InventoryItem(capacity: "1T", chainLength: 55, speed: "32FPM", voltage: "110V", frameSize: "Small", controlStation: "None"),
       InventoryItem(capacity: "1T", chainLength: 55, speed: "32FPM", voltage: "110V", frameSize: "Small", controlStation: "None"),
       InventoryItem(capacity: "1/2T", chainLength: 65, speed: "16FPM", voltage: "208V", frameSize: "Standard", controlStation: "Integrated"),
       InventoryItem(capacity: "1/2T", chainLength: 65, speed: "16FPM", voltage: "208V", frameSize: "Standard", controlStation: "Integrated"),
       InventoryItem(capacity: "1/2T", chainLength: 65, speed: "16FPM", voltage: "208V", frameSize: "Standard", controlStation: "Integrated"),
       InventoryItem(capacity: "1/2T", chainLength: 65, speed: "16FPM", voltage: "208V", frameSize: "Standard", controlStation: "Integrated")]
```

I want to group them into other array or dictionary where all of the elements have same attributes. Is there way to do it?

Comment: you can filter them on basis of any property

Comment: yeah but I can only filter by one property, all of the properties have to be same

Comment: try Comparable protocol and compare complete model and filter them accordingly

Comment: I would suggest Equatable as we need only the == operation. And then you could filter them

Comment: you can use NSPredicate for comparing with multiple fields. Please refer NSpredicate and NSCompoundPredicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adopt to this example by conforming `InventoryItem` to `Equatable`  and `Hashable` as below,

```
class InventoryItem: Equatable, Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int { return a.hashValue ^ b.hashValue ^ c.hashValue }

    static func == (lhs: InventoryItem, rhs: InventoryItem) -> Bool {
        return  lhs.a == rhs.a &&
                lhs.b == rhs.b &&
                lhs.c == rhs.c
    }

    var a: String
    var b: String
    var c: String

    init(_ a: String, b: String, c: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    }
}
```

Lets say we have this data,

```
let inv1 = InventoryItem("a", b: "b", c: "c")
let inv2 = InventoryItem("a", b: "b", c: "c")
let inv3 = InventoryItem("p", b: "q", c: "r")
let inv4 = InventoryItem("x", b: "y", c: "z")
let list = [inv1, inv2, inv3, inv4]

var groupedItems: [String: [InventoryItem]] = [:]

let unique = Set(list)
unique.forEach { (item) in
   groupedItems["\(item.hashValue)"] = list.filter({ $0 == item })
}

groupedItems.keys.forEach { key in
   let items = groupedItems[key]!
   print(items.count)
   items.forEach({ (item) in
       print("\(item.a)\(item.b)\(item.c)")
   })
}
```

Output:

```
1
xyz
1
pqr
2
abc
abc
```

**Note** If your `InventoryItem` is a `struct` or `enum` then you don't need to explicitly conform to `Equatable`, only conforming to `Hashable` is enough and you can just remove `hashValue` and equator method(`static func == (lhs: InventoryItem, rhs: InventoryItem) -> Bool`) from `InventoryItem`.

Comment: in that case I should know the object to compare with others. I need a solution to automatically group same objects where I know nothing about them